# Помогите разобраться с адресацией PHP

Tags: php

Прописал путь к файлу с библиотекой (rb-mysql.php) в файле который лежит в другой папке на том же уровне/глубине.

```
 require('/public_html/lib/rb-mysql.php');
```

В моем случае такой способ работает только кода нужный файл лежит в той же папке или в папке на уровень глубже, родитель который находится в папке с файлом, в котором реквайрим нужный файл. Прочитал что можно попробовать указать путь от корня... Тут свои нюансы: я использую бесплатный хост в котором мне доступна корневая папка, которая содержит папку сайтом (publick_html). Когда я получаю ошибку о том что php не нашел искомый файл, то вижу что путь гораздо глубже чем мне доступно через FTP.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю след ответ от сервера:

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/public_html/lib/rb-mysql.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd2/533/11928533/public_html/comp/db.php on line 2

Эти варианты вадают аналогичный результат, сервер все равно пытается найти файл исходя из папки "comp":

```
 require('/storage/ssd2/533/11928533/public_html/lib/rb-mysql.php');
 require('lib/rb-mysql.php');
```

По сути вопрос в следующем: как подключить файл который лежит в папке на уровень выше или в соседней папке?

Заранее спасибо, надеюсь описал достаточно точно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require('../lib/rb-mysql.php');`

Что бы выйти из папки, нужно указать: `../`

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Если не жалко времени, можно пару слов о функционале точек? Поднимают на уровень вверх или просто переносят точку отсчета в корневую папку?

Comment: Просто поднимают на один уровень вверх, что бы подняться на два уровня, нужно использовать `../../`, вообще не рекомендуется использовать многоуровневую структуру, но почти всегда так удобней. Если ответ Вам подошёл, укажите его, пожалуйста, как правильный.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ! Не сразу заметил кнопку подтверждения ответа)